# How To Remove the Vocals from a Song? Basic methods won't work

Tags: audio, vocals

I have an old song. I need to remove the vocals and get only the music from it. I used Audacity (Effects > Vocal Remover). After applying, there's no sound!

I used Audition (the Center Channel Extractor). After applying, a tiny noise came (a small squeeking). Nothing else.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This implies that your track is in mono. Centre channel extraction gets the difference of the L and R tracks - making the assumption that the difference broadly equates to a middle channel, which is usually where the vocals are.

If your song is old, it may have been recorded in mono, which means there is no difference between L and R channels (or almost no difference - the squeak is the difference)

In this circumstance, this question is a duplicate of [**Removal of Voice from single track in Audacity**](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/5244/674)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [MashTactic](http://www.quikquak.com/Prod_MashTactic.html), a special filter plugin for isolating areas in the frequency and stereo spectrum.
Here is a video that demonstrates it:

Answer (score 0):

Also there is ISSE: [An Interactive Source Separation Editor](https://isse.sourceforge.net) which is an opensource software based on what appears to be a research paper that permits visual identification of frequency clusters in timeline of a song, for isolation and separation. The identification is a manual process, but the outcome, in many cases is quite rewarding. There are a few youtube videos describing how to use it for fairly good vocal removal.